# Fill a binary tree with two functions

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I need to implement a binary tree in java, where the value of a right node is calculated with function1() which takes the parent and parent of parent nodes as input and the value of a  left node is calculated with function2() which takes the parent node as input. (for the first two child nodes, parent and parent of parent node values are pre-determined) 
The nodes are filled with the return values of their respective functions until one of the nodes has the value which the program is looking for. If the functions produce the desired value at some point, we need to print the path to that node, that is which order of functions produced the desired value. If the value is impossible to get with the given functions then we print out "false"

Could you please tell me the best way to implement this algorithm?

Edit: let's assume that:
1. function1 is :

```
int function1(p_node.value, p_node.p_node.value)
{ `return 5*p_node.value+6*p_node.p_node.value;}
```

2: function2 is:

```
int function2(p_node.value){
return 5*p_node;}
```

Then,

```
node.right_node.value=function1(node.p_node.value, node.p_node.pnode.value)
if(node.right_node.value==desired_output) "print path_to_the_node"
node.left_node.value=function2(node.p_node.value);
if(node.left_node.value==desired_output) "print path_to_the_node"
```

Comment: What is the definition of `function1()` and `function2()`? If I don't know I can't determine whether the value is possible to get.

Comment: you don't need to know anything about those functions since they just compute a value and store it in the node. that is it. I check manually after each computation if the function return value is the one which is requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). This is a sample:

```
void findPath(Node secondChildNode, int desiredOutput){
    Node n = breadthFirstSearch(secondChildNode, desiredOutput);
    if(n == null)
        System.out.println("false");
    else{
        ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(n != null){
            list.add(n);
            n = n.pNode;
        }
        for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.println(list.get(i).value);
    }
}
Node breadthFirstSearch(Node secondChildNode, int desiredOutput){
    if(!secondChildNode.isPossible())
        return null;
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(secondChildNode);
    Node t;
    while((t = q.poll()) != null){
        if(t.value == desiredOutput)
            return t;
        Node left = t.createLeftChild();
        if(left.isPossible(desiredOutput))
            q.add(left);
        Node right = t.createRightChild();
        if(right.isPossible(desiredOutput))
            q.add(right);
    }
    return null;
}
```

You need to implement `Node`, which is an easy and straightforward work.

```
class Node{
    Node pNode;
    int value;
    Node(Node pNode, int value){/* ... */}
    Node createLeftChild(){/* ... */}
    Node createRightChild(){/* ... */}
    boolean isPossible(int desiredOutput){
        return value <= desiredOutput;
    }
    /* ...... */
}
```

Now I see your definition of `function1()` and `function2()`. If `desiredOutput` is in the subtree of `node`, then `node.value <= desiredOutput`. Otherwise, the value of it's subtree grew larger and larger and one day **no** value of it's subtree `<= desiredOutput`. (Assume the value of root is positive)

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify a bit more. Please refer to the edited version.

Comment: @Ahmedov I've edited the answer to reflect your edit.